# Is there a name for the meetings between kings and peasants?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, middle-english

In the middle ages, or in fiction, when the king holds a ceremony of sorts to meet with commoners and disscuss their issues one by one, is there a word for that, or a common name that could be assosiated with this "meeting". Or can anyone think of anything that would sound good?

Comment: Look up definitions and synonyms of council, assembly and symposium.

Comment: Also look up "petition"--they have petitioned the king, as I recall, and he is seeing those he has agreed to see.

Answer (score 3):

Audience ([MWD](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/audience))

> a formal hearing or interview *an audience with the pope*

Answer (score 1):

> In the middle ages, or in fiction, when the king holds a ceremony of sorts to meet with commoners...

I stand to be corrected, but I can't think of a time when this happened. Why would a king do such a thing when the peasants were his possessions? He wasn't looking for votes or popularity. As a consequence, there is probably no word for it.

That said, there was a thing called a **moot**:

OED

> **1.a. A meeting, an assembly of people, esp. one for judicial or legislative purposes. Also: a place where a meeting is held.** *[Chiefly associated with organs of national and local administration from the Anglo-Saxon to the early modern period* (cf. gemot n., witenagemot n.).]
>
> c1175  (▸OE)    Ælfric Homily (Bodl. 343) in S. Irvine Old Eng. Homilies (1993) 37   *Heofene rice is ilic ane kynge, he ðe hæfde **mot** wið his men.*

but the lower orders would certainly not be there.

Comment: Perhaps it's only in fairy-tales (or certainly the "Arabian Nights") but I've read numerous stories where the hard-done-by peasant was able to approach the monarch and request justice (presumably because there wasn't any meaningful judicial system at the time). Not an "assembly" but rather one-on-one.

Comment: @equin0x80 The problem is that as this never happened in real life in England, there is no English word for it. In fiction, the situation is always described in a clause or two - there is no word.

Answer (score 0):

An [address](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/address). The king addresses his subjects?

> address noun [C] (SPEECH)   a formal speech
>
> address verb [T] (SPEAK TO)   C2 formal to speak or write to someone

Comment: Nice answer! Could you maybe add a definition and link the dictionary you got it from, and also explain _why_ that's a good word for this?